# Compute the Fourier Transform of $\frac1{x^2-2x+2}.$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, proof-verification

*Compute the Fourier Transform of* $$\frac1{x^2-2x+2}.$$

**My Answer:** The denominator has roots at $1+i, 1-i$. We try to calculate the answer by the residue theorem. If $\xi\leq0$, we can say that $$\int_{\gamma_R} \frac{e^{-i\xi z}}{z^2 -2z+2} \xrightarrow{R\to \infty} 0$$

if $\gamma_R$ is a semicircular path of radius $R$ in the upper half plane. Thus

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-it\xi}}{t^2 - 2x +2} dt= 2\pi i \operatorname{Res}_{z=1+i}{\frac {e^{-i\xi z}}  {z^2 - 2z +2}} = \pi e^{\xi - i \xi}.$$

Now since the function we're transforming is real, the F.T. should be hermitian...therefore $\hat{f}(\xi) = \pi e^{|\xi| - i\xi}$.

Right?

Comment: Not quite; it is $$\pi \, e^{-|\xi|-i \xi}$$

Comment: Maple code $$with(inttrans):
fourier(1/(x^2-2*x+2), x, xi);
  $$ outputs $$ {{\rm e}^{-i\xi}}\pi \, \left( {{\rm e}^{-\xi}}{\it Heaviside} \left( 
\xi \right) +{{\rm e}^{\xi}}{\it Heaviside} \left( -\xi \right) 
 \right)
 .$$